# Is there a way in python to trigger an action upon exiting a function

Tags: python, events

I'm in the process of adding a bit of code to a django system that needs to make a specific function call upon exiting a function.  Most of the code that I'm updating has several exit points throughout, which requires that I add a one-liner immediately before each one of them.  A wee bit ugly.

What I'd like to do is to simply say, "upon exiting this function, do this", much like the atexit module (from what I've found so far anyway), but to be triggered upon exiting the function rather than the entire script.

Is there anything I can use that works that way?

(I'm using Python 2.7.3 by the way)

Comment: decorator is one way to go

Comment: Does the "specific function call" require access to any local variables in the function from which you need to call it? Might help to clarify the question with some example code.

Comment: @Aya: The only thing it really needs access to is and ID that's passed in the function arguments.  It seems that a decorator will do the trick nicely.

Comment: @JacobEwing Decorator is probably cleanest then. You may also want to catch exceptions, call your function, then re-raise the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a decorator. That's simply a wrapper that surrounds the function: you can do what you like either before or after calling it.

```
def do_after(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        call_my_extra_function()
    return wrapper
```

and use it:

```
@do_after
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

Comment: You should return the return value of `func`. Would also be nice to parameterize `do_after` so it wasn't limited to `call_my_extra_function`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling that function, make a function that calls both

-function a (your function)

-function b (the exit function code)

call this meta function instead